# percentage of field dropped outside of drop area ,JQ Draggable and Droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

i m using Jquery DRAG&DROP for dragging elements. To prevent field from dropping outside of droppable revert option has been used.

```
$("#draggable").draggable({revert: "invalid",});
```

It works perfectly but it doesn't revert to last position if percentage of field moved out of droppable

[Js Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/23udp/6/)

Try to move portion of field outside droppable area and it will allow field to be dropped.

can some on guide me to how to fix it
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tolerance: 'fit'` to set the draggable item be dropped only if it is completely inside the droppable element:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable({revert: "invalid"});
    $("#Dropable").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("dropped!");
        },
        tolerance: 'fit'
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial", "Verdana", "sans-serif";
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
#draggable {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
#Dropable {
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>
<div id="Dropable">Droppable area</div>
```